# We got the following error: null, while trying to run this SQL script

Tags: sql, postgresql, scala, playframework, slick

I get the above error coming from Play Evolutions while running activator run on a new Scala Play-Slick project. I'm using Postgres server version 9.3 and the latest JDBC driver 9.4. My `1.sql` file looks like this:

```
# schema

# --- !Ups

CREATE TABLE country (
    id BIGINT,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    iso2 CHAR(2),
    modified TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now(),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_modified()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.modified = now();
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_country_modified BEFORE UPDATE ON country FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_modified();

# --- !Downs

DROP TABLE country CASCADE;

DROP FUNCTION update_modified_column;
```

By trial and error I see that Evolutions doesn't understand well the native Postgres trigger function `update_modified`. How can I solve or circumvent this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Play evolution plugin splits your .sql files into a series of semicolon-delimited statements before executing them one-by-one against the database.

As you are using semicolons within the function *update_modified()* code, you have to escape it by entering it twice **;;**. See below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_modified()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.modified = now();;
    RETURN NEW;;
END;;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```